# how to maintain state of button for each ngFor item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-directive, ngfor

I am integration Trello in my angular project. there is a start timer button for each & every card. suppose when the user clicks on the start timer button of a card A, that button replace with end task button. the problem is here the end button is appearing in all cards. 
If I click on the start button timer of a Card A. that button should replace only on card A. it should not change on all cards[image]

in the above image in section 1 I have start timer button when I click on the button it replaces with end timer button as displayed in section 2 but when I clock the modal window & click on another card It displays the end timer button on another card too. expected is if I click on card A button it should replace only on card A for card B it should display the start timer button.

Thank you in advance.

Following is my code -

```
startTimer() {
    this.startFlag = !this.startFlag;
}

activityModal(id, name, due) {
    jQuery("#activityModal").modal('show');

    this.cardDueDate = due;
    this.mainCardName = name;
    this.mainCardId = id;
}

// card iterates
<div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters overflow">
  <section class="list" *ngFor="let item of mainListArr" id="{{item.id}}">
    <header>{{item.name}}</header>
    <article class="card" *ngFor="let card of item.cards">
      <a (click)="activityModal(card.id, card.name,card.due)">
        <header>{{card.name}}</header>
        <div class="detail badge is-due-complete" *ngIf="card.due != null">
          <i class="badge-icon fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
          <span class="badge-text">{{card.due | date : 'MMM dd'}}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>


// modal popup code

<!-- Modal for activity -->
<div class="modal fade" id="activityModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="activityModal"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" *ngIf="mainCardName !== ''">{{mainCardName}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeActivityModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9">
          some code here
           </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center vertical-center">
            <small><u>Card Actions</u></small>

            <button class="btn btn-action mar-t-05" (click)="startTimer()" *ngIf="startFlag">Start Timer</button>
            <button class="btn btn-action mar-t-05" (click)="endTimer()" *ngIf="!startFlag">End Timer</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the button in each card have the same variable to show or hide the start and end timer.

The easiest way is to send in the index value for cards in the startTimer and endTimer functions and use this index to have a unique value of flag for each card.